# MongoCxx 3.1.0 How can I close connection?

Tags: c++, mongodb, c++11, mongo-cxx-driver

I have program which may have few connections and I need close each one connections.
Help me please.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <bsoncxx/builder/stream/document.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>

#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>

int main(int, char**) {
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client conn{mongocxx::uri{}};

    bsoncxx::builder::stream::document document{};

    auto collection = conn["testdb"]["testcollection"];
    document << "hello" << "world";

    collection.insert_one(document.view());
    auto cursor = collection.find({});

    for (auto&& doc : cursor) {
        std::cout << bsoncxx::to_json(doc) << std::endl;
    }
    need close connection

}
```

conn.close() or how can I close it?

Comment: you no need to explicitly close the mongo connection. there is no close method available.

Answer (score 5):

`mongocxx::client` doesn't provide an explicit disconnect or close method because it is actually a wrapper around another internal, private client class that has a destructor that terminates the connection.

If you look at the `mongocxx::client` declaration, it contains a member [`std::unique_ptr<impl> _impl`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/mongocxx/client.hpp#L218).

This is a unique pointer to an instance of [`mongocxx::client::impl`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/mongocxx/private/client.hh) which implements a destructor that calls `libmongoc::client_destroy(client_t);` when your client object is destroyed.

If your application is going to be connecting/reconnecting many times, you might be interested in using [`mongocxx::Pool`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/api/mongocxx-v3/classmongocxx_1_1pool.html), which manages a number of connections to a MongoDB instance, and then you can obtain a connection from it when necessary. It's also the recommended way to use `mongocxx` if you're in a multithreaded application, as the standard `mongocxx:client` is not thread-safe.